# JAXB inheritance dymanically named tags

Tags: java, jaxb

I am working on a configuration XML file, which I'd like to be dynamic.

I have the following classes:

**Repository:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "repository")
public class Repository
        implements Serializable
{

    @XmlElement(name = "custom-configuration")
    private CustomConfiguration customConfiguration;

    ...
    // Constructor

    // Getters and setters
}
```

**CustomConfiguration:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CustomConfiguration
{
}
```

**FooBarConfiguration:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo-bar-configuration")
public class FooBarConfiguration extends CustomConfiguration
{

    @XmlAttribute
    private String bucket;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String key;


    public FooBarConfiguration()
    {
    }

    public String getBucket()
    {
        return bucket;
    }

    public void setBucket(String bucket)
    {
        this.bucket = bucket;
    }

    public String getKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }

}
```

This is what I would like to have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<repository id="test-repository">
    <foo-bar-configuration bucket="test-bucket" key="test-key"/>
    <group/>
</repository>
```

This is what I'm getting instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<repository id="test-repository">
    <customConfiguration xsi:type="fooBarConfiguration" bucket="test-bucket" key="test-key" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <group/>
</repository>
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here's a real-world example.

[Schema declares and abstract element](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/fb5be05067d542d7cba9c5c43ea3de3967bfb5cd/schemas/src/main/resources-original/ogc/filter/2.0/query.xsd#L19-L20) of some base type:

```
   <xsd:element name="AbstractQueryExpression"
                type="fes:AbstractQueryExpressionType" abstract="true"/>
```

[This is how it's used](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/fb5be05067d542d7cba9c5c43ea3de3967bfb5cd/schemas/src/main/resources-original/ogc/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd#L307):

```
   <xsd:complexType name="GetPropertyValueType">
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="wfs:BaseRequestType">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element ref="fes:AbstractQueryExpression"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="valueReference" type="xsd:string"
               use="required"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="resolvePath" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attributeGroup ref="wfs:StandardPresentationParameters"/>
            <xsd:attributeGroup ref="wfs:StandardResolveParameters"/>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
```

Which results in the following Java code:

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "AbstractQueryExpression", namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<?> abstractQueryExpression;
```

[Another schema declares an element which may substitute the original element](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/fb5be05067d542d7cba9c5c43ea3de3967bfb5cd/schemas/src/main/resources/ogc/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd#L158-L159):

```
   <xsd:element name="StoredQuery" type="wfs:StoredQueryType"
      substitutionGroup="fes:AbstractQueryExpression"/>
```

In `ObjectFactory` this looks as follows:

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0", name = "StoredQuery", substitutionHeadNamespace = "http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0", substitutionHeadName = "AbstractQueryExpression")
public JAXBElement<StoredQueryType> createStoredQuery(StoredQueryType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<StoredQueryType>(_StoredQuery_QNAME, StoredQueryType.class, null, value);
}
```

This mechanism may be used to implement "extension points". You declare and use an abstract/generic "substitution head" element and in other schemas specific elements may substitute it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is I'm not using an XSD. I have classes which can extend the `CustomConfiguration` that are not known. They may, or not be on the classpath, so I can't just write an `ObjectMapper` that easily (because I would have to know the names of these classes in advance). Any other suggestions?

Comment: @carlspring You don't need XSD and also don't need to know classes in advance. Place `ObjectFactory` where your extension classes are. Use it in runtime when building JAXB context. No need to know these classes in compile time.

Comment: Do you think you could maybe have a quick look at my diff here: https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/pull/183/files and tell me what I'm doing wrong? (If you'd like to build the code, please check here: https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/wiki/Building-the-code). This is the error I'm getting: https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/pull/183/commits/9bdc666c32e7ba04df2e1befe7655050c1652bc9.

Comment: The diff is small and contains all the classes involved (which are just a handful). I have put the two which extend `CustomConfiguration` in separate packages, because in a real-life scenario, they won't be part of the same module (and I won't know their names).

Comment: @carlspring I've added a couple of comments. I can't take a look at the unit test at the moment, will take a look later. The error you're getting is probably because you don't provide `org.carlspring.strongbox.storage.repository.aws` and other packages to the `JAXBContext` when you create it. I can take a look at this a bit later.

Comment: Thanks! We will give these a try within the next couple of hours (I hope). If you get a chance to play around it before me, please, let me know, if you get to fix it! Much appreciated!

Comment: I'll get to it in around 6 hours.

Comment: Hey! Were you able to give it another go?

Comment: I'm on it this very second

Comment: [Here you go](https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/pull/186). Your test is green now, unmarshalling also works. I only had to rename `ObjectFactory` classes and add `@XmlElementDecl`. Appears you don't need `JAXBElement` wrapping if your configuration classes are annotated with `@XmlElementRoot`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to marshal by element name using `@XmlElementRef`, for example:

```
@XmlElementRef
private CustomConfiguration customConfiguration;
```

Here's an example from Blaise Doughan: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html

Comment: This looks like a great idea. The problem is that the idea is this -- this field is here so that custom implementations could be made. I don't know what they will be. They are outside the scope of our application. Hence, I don't know what the names of the field will be. This is why I'm trying to make this look so generic. Is this possible?

Comment: @carlspring You can do `@XmlElementRef protected JAXBElement<CustomConfiguration>`. You extension modules will have to provide an `ObjectFactory` with `@XmlElementDecl(substitutionHeadName="custom-configuration")`. This patern is called subsitution groups. You basically say that you `FooBarConfiguration` may substitute `CustomConfiguration`.

Comment: @lexicore: Would you mind knocking up a brief example for this case? Especially, the factory part...